# Android: App needs to blur out when in the recent Recent/App Overview

Tags: android, android-recents

Usecase: User should be able to take the screen shots in the application,
application should blur out when it goes to Recent App.

Can't use android:excludeFromRecents in the AndroidManifest.xml as it will remove it from the recent app leaving the users lost.

Cannot use the FLAG_SECURE in the onCreate() method, as the app has to allow users to take screen shots.
Neither I can set the FLAG_SECURE in onPause() and reset in onResume() as there is no guarantee that the activity will be paused when entering Recent Apps as the activity is still in resumed state.

Any Suggestions how can it be achieved